# A ship sails to an island . Find the average sailing speed for the whole journey.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A ship sails to an island at the rate of $15$ $km/h$ and sails back to the starting point at $10$ $km/h$. Find the average sailing speed for the whole journey.

What I tried,
Let the distance be $x$ $km$
Speed from starting point to island $=15$ $km/h$
Speed from island to St point $=10$ $km/h$
Time taken in first case= $\frac{x}{15}$ $h$
Similarly time taken in second case=$\frac{x}{10}$ $h$
What to do next?

Comment: barak gives the correct answer below, but as a shortcut for averaging two speeds, you can use the method of averaging the inverse of the two speeds and then inverting that.  So you would take the average of $\frac{1}{15}$ and $\frac{1}{10}$ and then take the inverse of that.  It's called the harmonic mean I believe.  And you can further manipulate this to see that the average speed when traveling the same distance at $x$ and $y$ velocity is $\frac{2xy}{x+y}$

Comment: @turkeyhundt: it is indeed the harmonic mean.  Meanwhile if the boat sailed for a given time at $15km/h$ and then for the same time at $10km/h$ you would use the arithmetic mean to get the average speed.  But since it is possible to confuse the two means, and it is more complicated if the two distances or times are not the same, it may be safer to do barak's calculation.

Comment: How did this become a hot question???

Comment: Because everyone loves islands, and boats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $d$ denote the one-way distance.

It took the ship $\frac{d}{15}$ hours to get to the island.

It took the ship $\frac{d}{10}$ hours to get back from the island.

---

The total distance was $2d$.

The total travel-time was $\frac{d}{15}+\frac{d}{10}=\frac{5d}{30}=\frac{d}{6}$.

Hence the average speed was $\frac{2d}{\frac{d}{6}}=12$ km per hour.